Why doesn't the option "Force Quit" in the "[Program] not responding" dialog ever work?
Every once in a while, I guess we all experience a program that doesn't respond for any number of reasons. For me, it's most often if I accidentally try to open a file from a remote location that's no longer accessible.
But for whatever reason, this dialog has two options "Force Quit" and "Wait", and they always do exactly the same thing: Nothing. Except dismiss the dialog only to pop up again a few seconds later. And it's been this way for years.
So I'm not asking how to quit a program - I know about kill -9 and pkill. I'm asking how it can be that a simple function "quit this program now" simply never works?

Hmm. Works for me reliably. However, it usually occurs when the system is a bit busy, so the "kill" selection waits in queue.
